# Linux 64bits : cross-compile for 32bits target using cmake

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, cross-compiling, 32bit-64bit

I'm using *gcc*+*cmake* in a Linux 64bits and my compilation target is Linux 32bits.

So I added `-m32` to my *CMAKE_C_FLAGS*.

But then *cmake* fails with the message: `The C compiler "/usr/bin/gcc" is not able to compile a simple test program.`

Of course, this is because a 32bits executable can't run on 64bits arch.

I had a look on the [cross compilation cmake's page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux), but it seems very complex for my need.

So, my question : is there a way to simply build a 32bits binary (exe or lib) using *cmake*?

For information, here is what I tried by using an environment variable:

1. Add `` `${myflag}` `` to *CMAKE_C_FLAGS*
2. Set *myflag* to empty.
3. Call *cmake* to generate a makefile (so it will successfully check the compiler)
4. Set *myflag* to `-m32`.
5. Call *make* (so it will compile with my -m32 option

But it seems that *gcc* doesn't evaluate user environment variables.

Comment: Most Linux distributions have compatibility 32-bit libraries, needed to run 32-bit programs even on 64-bit systems. If you haven't installed them you need to do that.

Comment: I understood that this is not about cross compilation, but just about arch, so I completely rewrite my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60705531/execute-32bits-exe-with-ubuntu-18-04-64bits-within-a-windows10-subsystem-for-lin